# scrollToRowAtIndexPath issue with userInteraction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently using automatic scroll to bottom in `UITableView`, but there is a bug to solve:

If I press in any location of my `UITableView` before the scroll is executed that stop to work. (I cannot scroll to bottom before the view is displayed because I retrieve async data)
So the first thing I thought is tho disable the `userInteraction` like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        ...
}
```

And to unlock it here:

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {        
    let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        let numberOfSections = self.tableView.numberOfSections
        let numberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: animated)

        }
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    })
}
```

But (it's really strange) is not working, yes the view is disabled (I've tried even to lock the UITableView) and I can not scroll the UITableView but it seems that it can retrieve anyway the touch.

Comment: I've solved using:

Comment: `func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

    }`